# Is this inequality correct? (inequality with incomplete gamma function)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function, differential

Is the following inequality true for all $t_1, t_2, P, \alpha$? How I can show/prove that?

$$\alpha\int_{n\times t_1}^\frac{n\times t_1}{1+P} t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt+ (1-\alpha)\int_{n\times t_2}^\frac{n\times t_2}{1+P}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt > \int_{n(\alpha t_1 + (1 - \alpha)t_2)}^\frac{n(\alpha t_1 + (1 - \alpha)t_2)}{1+P}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt$$
where $t_2>t_1 > 0$, $P>0$, $0<\alpha<1$ and $n$ is a large positive integer.

Thanks.

Comment: You have $P$ in your assumptions, $p$ in your inequality, and (if that's in reality the same variable) upper integration bounds lower than the lower bounds, so all of your integrals (if we tacitly add the missing $dt$ to make them integrals) are negative. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I fixed that. Yes, that's what I want.